# Merge sort implementation questions in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, sentinel

I'm in an algorithms course and am learning about merge sort. Our professor recommended we try to implement the pseudo code provided in the book.

1. Am I correct in using Integer.MAX_VALUE as a sentinel value when
   sorting an array of integers (used in lines 8 & 9 in the Merge
   method pseudo code below)?
2. For line 2 of the Merge-Sort pseudo code method, is it correct to code that in Java using Math.ceil() like I did? (Edit: It's actually floor and I updated my code to reflect this.)

If you see any other mistakes please let me know!

Here is the pseudo code the book gives for merge sort.
[image: merge sort algorithm part 1]

[image: merge sort algorithm part 2]

And, here is how I coded it in Java:

```
public void mergeSort(int[] arrNums, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        mergeSort(arrNums, p, q);
        mergeSort(arrNums, q + 1, r);
        merge(arrNums, p, q, r);
    }
}

public void merge(int[] arrNums, int p, int q, int r) {
    int nOne = q - p + 1;
    int nTwo = r - q;

    int[] arrLeft = new int[nOne + 1];
    int[] arrRight = new int[nTwo + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < nOne; i++) {
        arrLeft[i] = arrNums[p + i - 1];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nTwo; j++) {
        arrRight[j] = arrNums[q + j];
    }

    arrLeft[nOne] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    arrRight[nTwo] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    // Tracks arrLeft index
    int i = 0;

    // Tracks arrRight index
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = p; k < r; k++) {
        if (arrLeft[i] <= arrRight[j]) {
            arrNums[k] = arrLeft[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arrNums[k] = arrRight[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not `ceil` in the pseudo code, it's `floor`. And if you operate on integers, that's implied anyway.

Comment: An alternative to using infinity.. is to check if the left or right arrays has no more variables, then you dumb the remainder of the another one into the main array.

Comment: @ShadyAtef "dumb the remainder??"  Did you mean "dump"?

Comment: @ajb, Yes.. that's true.

Comment: In most libraries, a variation of bottom up merge sort is more common. Wiki has simple examples of top down and bottom up merge sort for arrays and linked lists. [Wiki merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Usually there's a one time allocation of a working array the same (or 1/2) the size of the original array, and the direction of merge alternates with iteration pass or in the case of top down merge sort with level of recursion (this avoids unnecessary copying of data).

Comment: For the sentinel value, I did this :
L[n1] = R[n2] = (L[n1 - 1] > R[n2 - 1]) ? L[n1 - 1] + 1 : R[n2 - 1] + 1;

The logic is simple, the sentinel value needs to be anything greater than the last elements(A[q] & A[r]) of sub array A[p...q] and A[q+1...r]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `for` loop in your `merge` method, variable `k` should start from `p - 1`:

```
for (int k = p - 1; k < r; k++) {
    if (arrLeft[i] <= arrRight[j]) {
        arrNums[k] = arrLeft[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        arrNums[k] = arrRight[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Pseudo code in many text books likes to start array index from `1`, so here you need to subtract it by 1.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it a few days ago, if someone will be interested.

```
private static void mergeSort(double[] arr, int start, int end){
    if(start < end){
        int mid = ( start + end ) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, start, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end);
        Merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}


private static void Merge(double[] arr, int start, int mid, int end){

    double[] leftArray = new double[mid - start + 2];
    double[] rightArray = new double[end - mid + 1];
    for(int i = start; i <= mid; i++ )
        leftArray[i - start] = arr[i];
    for (int i = mid + 1; i <= end; i++ )
        rightArray[i - mid - 1] = arr[i];

    leftArray[mid - start + 1] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    rightArray[end - mid] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    int leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 0;

    for (int k = start; k <= end; k++){
        if(leftArray[leftIndex] <= rightArray[rightIndex])
            arr[k] = leftArray[leftIndex++];
        else
            arr[k] = rightArray[rightIndex++];
    }   
}
```